# Heroku Push Fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, rubygems, bundler

When I push to heroku, it tells me that it fails to install gems with bundler and then it fails:

```
Git error: command `git fetch --force --quiet --tags 'git@github.com:holgersindbaek/streama.git' "refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*"` in directory /tmp/build_2e6gwsce8rtbt/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/cache/bundler/git/streama-bb31e974eacf3e56d77c4899ae1e3687c8245251 has failed.
           If this error persists you could try removing the cache directory '/tmp/build_2e6gwsce8rtbt/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/cache/bundler/git/streama-bb31e974eacf3e56d77c4899ae1e3687c8245251'
     !
     !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
     !
     !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/rails app

    To git@heroku.com:afternoon-spring-7047.git
     ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
    error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:afternoon-spring-7047.git'
```

It suggest that I remove the stream-chace, but I have no idea where that is.

Has anyone tried this before?

I'm on Rails 3.2.2, running MongoDB with Mongoid.

UPDATE:

I'm using ruby 1.9.3, so I think it's a bit funny it points me to a ruby 1.9.1 folder. Don't know if that has anything to do with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the private git link for that repository:

```
git@github.com...
```

rather than:

```
git://github.com...
```

Because the Heroku shell isn't authorized to "privately" clone that GitHub repository, attempting to run `bundle install` on Heroku will fail. Change that link to the public clone URL.

Comment: That worked. Thanks a lot. It's funny though... I have another gem that I'm using from a private repository and that works fine.